# one to one annotation doesn't insert foreign key into a table

Tags: java, sql, database, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to add information into 2 tables with one to one annotation. [image]

[image]

As you can see votes_id and voter_sinNumber doesn't insert foreign keys. 
here is my dao.java methods

```
public void addVoter(Voter voter) { 
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(voter);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();    
    }


    public void addVote(Votes votes) {  
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();


        Voter voter = new Voter();
        voter.setVotes(votes);
        votes.setVoter(voter);

        session.save(votes);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();    
    }
```

And this is how I declare Voter and votes:

Votes.java:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Votes implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private int id;

    private String party;

    public Votes(String party) {
        this.party = party;
}

    @OneToOne
    private Voter voter;


}
```

Voter.java:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Voter.byName", query="from Voter where sinNumber=:sinNumber")
public class Voter implements Serializable{
    @Id
    private int sinNumber;

    private String fname;
    private String lname;
    private int year; 
    private int month; 
    private int day; 

    private String address;


    @OneToOne
    private Votes votes;


    public Voter(int sinNumber, String fname, String lname, 
            int year, int month, int day, String address) {
        this.sinNumber = sinNumber;
        this.fname = fname;
        this.lname = lname;
        this.year = year;
        this.month = month;
        this.day = day;
        this.address = address;
    }


    public Voter(String fname, String lname, int year, int month, int day, 
            String address, Votes votes) {
        this.fname = fname;
        this.lname = lname;
        this.year = year;
        this.month = month;
        this.day = day;
        this.address = address;
        this.votes = votes;
    }


}
```

It throws an error:

> java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`hibernatedb`.`votes`, CONSTRAINT `FKdyr88aepaxedeiivxepemku28` FOREIGN KEY (`voter_sinNumber`) REFERENCES `voter` (`sinnumber`))

Comment: pls, add full code of Votes.java, Voter.java

Comment: Have you defined an owning side, i.e. does one of the fields define a [`@JoinColum`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html)? Normally, only one of the tables (`Vote` or `Voter`) needs a foreign key column). Also, do you define the schema through some `schema.sql` or is the schema autogenerated by JPA?

Comment: I did't use @JoinColum. I am using hibernate.cfg.xml and dao.java to access sql database

Comment: @Mate just added code

Comment: try adding @JoinColumn(name = "voter_sinnumber") in Votes.voter just above to  @OneToOne ... check full explanation https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: @Mate I tried that one already, gives the same errors. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cascade changes:

```
// On Voter side
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Votes votes;

// On Votes side
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Voter voter;
```

Comment: @Andrnicus it works but, I assume I am setting voter and votes in dao.java class wrong, because ion voter it inserts right votes id but it creates a new record instead of updating existing one, and in votes table it does not insert sin number, it inserts '0'

Comment: @Ana it's because of state impact on `equals` and `hashCode`, here are more details: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-implement-equals-hashcode-and-tostring-with-jpa-and-hibernate/